# How to define AssemblyProduct in csproj with the new csproj build system

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, csproj, .net-standard

In the "old" world I would define an `AssemblyProductAttribute` and `AssemblyTrademarkAttribute` that would the show up as "Product name" and "Legal trademarks" in the file propeties in windows explorer.

In the new simplified msbuild system which is used in Visual Studio 2017 for netstandard projects, the preferred way is to define all those assembly level attributes [in the csproj directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj) and let msbuild generate the actual attributes.

But it seems there is no way to define "Product name" and "Legal trademarks" in csproj. Or is there? [This msbuild target](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/release/2.0.0/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/build/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets) seems to hint that it should at leat work for the `AssemblyProductAttribute`.

How can I add those two things?

**Udapte:**
Ok, so for the AssemblyProductAttribute in can write `<Product>Foo</Product>` right into the csproj file. But what about the `AssemblyTrademarkAttribute`?

Comment: Just because they added a property page to the IDE does not make it the preferred way.  Particularly not for programmers that port old projects I imagine.  Using the old style with an attribute in code still works, you can put [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("foobar")] anywhere.

Comment: I was asuming that it is the preferred way, because when you define the attribute in code and then use that property page, you will get an compiler error abbout duplicate attributes. In earlier version of VS this modified the attributes in the code (AssemblyInfo.cs), but not anymore.

Comment: One can always create a new cs file and put assembly attributes into it so it doesn't really matter. The msbuild-integrated version is nicer though since you can use properties and define single imported msbuild files to set values for all projects etc. (even for crossing mixed f#+c# solutions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an item for assembly attributes not already emitted by these targets:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Reflection.AssemblyTrademarkAttribute">
    <_Parameter1>My Trademark</_Parameter1>
  </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```

An example can be seen [here](https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service/blob/2a808340e4cfb67a784a00f6515819369f72ecd6/src/DasMulli.Win32.ServiceUtils/DasMulli.Win32.ServiceUtils.csproj#L21-L28) for how it can be used to generate `InternalsVisibleTo` attributes.